# Is there a quick way to say If notempty x = y else x = default in a Linq where query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Is there a quick way to say

```
Where (data.x == (If notempty x = y else x = default))
```

Assuming the data being compared is both strings

```
Compare listitem.string with passed.string - if passed.string isnotempty, else passed.string equals default value.
```

in a Linq 'where` query.

Apologies that the question was really badly written.

... As per the comments updated ...

Comment: You should be a little more expressive as to what "x" and "y" represent and what's their actual type.

Comment: You have assignment and equality in the expression?

Comment: Could you please clarify what the `notempty` refers to?

Comment: @Chris M - maybe you should write the code in straightforward imperative C#, so people can suggest how to translate it into Linq. At the moment you've just got people guessing at what you might mean.

Comment: Is `data.x` or `y` the current item? Anyway, I've updated my post givne your modifications.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that, at writing I couldn't think of a better way of saying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, with your clarifications to the original post, I think I see what you're getting at now.

Try the following clause (where `data.x` is your current element and `y` in the passed argument).

```
where y == (string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) ? "default" : data.x)
```

I do not believe it's possible to use the null coalescing operator here, since the variables you are comparing and returning are different.

**Old Post:**
If what is empty? I'm guessing you're referring to `y`.

For a generic type `T`, you could use the following clause:

```
where data.x == (y ?? DefaultValue<T>())
```

where `DefaultValue` is a generic function of `T` that returns a so-called "default" value.

Comment: `(y ?? default(T))` is `(y != default(T) ? y : default(T))` which is just `y`

Comment: Good point. It should just be an arbitrary function rather than the `default` keyword.

Comment: Yep thanks to all on that one; and as well to 280Z28 for the MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: Fine, I'll concede this one to you +1. ;) I do find this type of question entertaining though, almost more so than ones with a straight answer because a gambling factor is involved. :)

Comment: @280Z28: Hehe, thanks. And yeah, the question was somewhat exciting (at least quite atypical) in that we were effectively placing our bets on the possibilities...

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the data type of x and y, but say they are strings:

```
Where (data.x == (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) ? y : "default"))
```

It's called the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: This is probably close to what the OP wants. Note however that evaluating `!foo` in a conditional (`!string.IsNullOrEmpty(y)` here) is considered bad practice. Much simpler just to switch the order of your true/false return values. :)

Comment: @Noldorin: I know, just didn't want to swap things around to much in comparison to the snippet in the question; good point to raise still, thanks for that.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. For consistency, it probably makes sense to leave it this way. (It also corresponds more to the null coalescing operator.)

Comment: If this is the case, and `y` is a "passed string", then it would be better to set `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(y)) y = "defaultValue";` before executing the Linq query. This is part of parameter validation.

Answer (score 3):

Your original post could be interpreted to be this:

```
where (data.x ?? y) == y
```

Edit: I am now pretty sure this is what you were attempting. :)

Edit 2: This is the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Edit 3: Whoever voted me down should post a reason. I interpreted the first post as: "If x is not empty, it should equal y, but it's ok to equal default(typeof y)." For reference types *or* nullable types, my post is correct.

Edit 4: Mine still *could be* the cleanest answer to his updated post. I keep reading it and it's still strangely worded. The `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(y))` post is the other possibility.

Comment: Admittedly the question isn't very clear, but I highly doubt this is what the OP wants. You've got x and y the wrong way round for a start.

Comment: Check my edit. This wording makes sense in the original post, and here's how it might be used. "If the user entered option *y*, do something. Also, *y* is the default, so if they didn't enter anything, that's ok too." That's just one example.

Comment: There's no indication that this "default" value is `y`. In fact, quite the opposite - I don't see how it could be.

Comment: "default" would refer to the type of both `data.x` and `y`. It's a `where` clause, so I have to assume he didn't mean assignment.

Comment: The `=` in the clause definitely means assignment, since he's using `==` for equality, which is standard. `x` would just seem to be a temporary variable. The syntax is slightly ambiguous though, I would concede.

Comment: That's assuming it was perfectly written in the OP. You have to read through things when they're clearly focusing on concepts over syntax.